# Problems to rewrite URL with Laravel, Wordpress and Apache

Tags: wordpress, laravel, apache, .htaccess, nginx

I have a question / problem with a Laravel project and Wordpress

My Laravel project is multilanguage and the URL is:https://example.com/en/ (look at the /en/)

This project use a blog in Wordpress with this URL https://example.com/en/news

If the directory /en/ exists physically, Apache reads the directory before the friendly path of my project (https://example.com/en is the homepage). The error code is 403, empty directory obviusly.

I tried to move the WordPress installation to another folder like /wordpress/ and rewrite the path of that folder using htaccess but it doesn't work.

I don't know if it's because this doesn't work, or because what I'm trying is impossible

This is the htaccess of the public folder with the Laravel project. I'm using a Plesk server with Apache + Nginx

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>


RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: "This is the htaccess of the public folder" - The `/public` folder being a physical directory in the document root? Then you must have another `.htaccess` file in the document root to route requests to the `/public` directory that contains your Laravel application? Otherwise `/public` would need to be part of the URL (which I assume it isn't? "Apache reads the directory before the friendly path of my project" - Well, not really - it looks like you simply aren't routing the request?

Comment: I think it may be preferable to have the WordPress app entirely separate and keep the `/en` "directory" as a _virtual_ path segment (not a physical directory) then route the Laravel and WordPress requests based on the initial URL-path. But it would be useful to know what other `.htaccess` files you have currently.

Comment: @MrWhite, I have only one .htaccess in my public folder (/httpdocs), this .htaccess manage all the request made to Laravel app. The WP is in the public folder to access it easily and avoid get it out of there for security reasons. I just need to show the content of the WP when someone enter to /en/news, actually the WP is in the public folder /wordpress/news, is there a way to change it on the URL and not creating the /en/news folder?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ignore the empty folder (403) and pass the URI to the Laravel controller with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63167421/ignore-the-empty-folder-403-and-pass-the-uri-to-the-laravel-controller-with-h)