# Ignore the empty folder (403) and pass the URI to the Laravel controller with .htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, apache, .htaccess

I have a project with Laravel and inside the public folder (`httpdocs`) I have a folder `/en/news`, all works fine with the route `/en/news` but when I try to go to the `/en` I have a 403 error because it is a empty folder, the real problem there is that `/en` is a route in my Laravel project with the homepage of the web, so first executes de `.htaccess` and throw the 403.
Is there any way to ignore this error for this specific folder/route (`/en`) or something like that?

My `.htaccess` is the tipical Laravel `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>
    
RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Why you tagged [tag:wordpress]?

Comment: The RewriteConds with flags `!-d` and `!-f` check that what was requested does not match an existing directory or file - so this prevents your request for `/en/` to be passed on to the index.php. You don’t want to completely disable that check for directories, otherwise you won’t be able to access _any_ directory directly any more. But what exact solution you need here, depends on what URLs you actually want to rewrite.

Comment: @CBroe , I want to rewrite the URL `https://myweb.com/en`  to show the page managed with Laravel and not the empty folder (403). How I can add the rule with the `!-d` and `!-f` for this case?

Comment: If it is _only_ that URL, then I would simply insert a new rule before the `# Send Requests To Front Controller...` comment line, that rewrites just that to the index.php - `RewriteRule ^en$ index.php [L]`

Comment: @CBroe it works!!! I just changed the `^en$` for `^en/$`, thanks you!!!

Answer (score 1):

The solution:

Add before the `# Send Requests To Front Controller...` the next rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^en/$ index.php [L]
```

This send the request to the index.php ignoring the checks for this specific route.